# Combine fields from points and polygon datasets using ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, esri-geodatabase, merge, union

I've a large number of points and polygons file; one or more one points are inside a specific polygon as reported in attached images.

The point file has 3 columns whilst the polygon file has 2 columns (none of these 5 column have same value, no possibility to merge in according similar column).

I want to obtain a new point layer (with all 5 columns) deriving from spatial question; so to obtain a sum of values of single polygon with values of all point contained inside them.

How can I do this?

[image: Example]

I am using a geodatabase, my version is 10.1.

Comment: You have a tag for spatial-database but are you using a file geodatabase or something else?  What version of ArcGIS Desktop are you using?

Comment: Hi PolyGeo, I using a geodatabase, my version is 10.1

Comment: Please **edit the question** in response to requests for clarification.  If you take the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour), you'll see that editing the question is your principal responsibility.  "Geodatabase" does not answer the question "File geodatabase or something else?", since "something else" includes "enterprise geodatabase" and "personal geodatabase".

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure this is what you want but you can join polygon data to the Points using tool [Spatial Join](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/spatial-join.htm) with Points as target features and polygon as join features:

> Joins attributes from one feature to another based on the spatial
>   relationship. The target features and the joined attributes from the
>   join features are written to the output feature class.

Comment: A few more details, To Sum Values using a Spatial Join with Polygon and Points, The Output Field, in Field Mapper must be Numeric (Double,Int,Float,etc). You can add a new field for the Sum if you want. Right-click your field and Add various columns from the Polygon and Point layer. Select Merge Rule, Sum.